# Mesos real world use-cases

Tags: mesos

I'm trying to figure out what would be the reasons for using Mesos. Can you come up with other ones?

1. Running all of your services in the same cluster instead of dedicated clusters (your end-applications + DevOps such as Jenkins)
2. Running different maturity applications in same cluster (dev, test, production), or is this viable? Kubernetes has a similar approach with Labels
3. Mesos simplifies the use of traditional distributed applications such as Hadoop by easing deployment, unified API, bin-packing of resources

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Full-disclosure: I currently work at Twitter and I'm involved in both Apache Mesos and Aurora.*

Mesos uses cases can vary based upon a few dimensions: scale (10 servers vs 10s of thousands), available hardware (dedicated/static or in the public cloud/scalable), and workloads (primarily services, batch, or both).

Your list is a great start. Here are a few additional use cases / features to add.

**Container Orchestration**

As container runtimes like Docker have become popular, lots of potential users are looking at Mesos + a scheduler to manage orchestration once container images are created. Mesos is already quite mature and has been proven at scale, which I think has given it a leg up over some emergent solutions.

**Increased Resource Utilization**

For companies running >50 servers, a common motivation for adopting Mesos is to increase resource utilization to reduce CapEx. There are a number of examples of this in both the public and private cloud. In the case of Ebay they have been running Jenkins on Mesos and were able to reduce their VM footprint. Mesosphere has also published a [case study of HubSpot](https://mesosphere.com/mesos-case-study-hubspot/) (runnning on AWS), and how they've been able to replace hundreds of smaller servers with dozens of larger ones by more-efficiently using their available hardware.

**Preemption**

At Twitter we're running Mesos via one scheduler: [Apache Aurora](http://aurora.apache.org). One of the ways we can improve utilization relates to your use case: running different maturity applications in the same cluster. Aurora has a concept of environments, so you can run applications that are production, development, or test. Additionally, Aurora has a built-in preemption feature which allows it to prioritize production over non-production tasks, killing non-production tasks when those resources are needed to run production ones as well as a priority system within each environment.

Long-term, functionality related to preemption will also be located in the Mesos core itself -- it's a killer feature related to both increased resource utilization and running different maturity applications (dev, test, prod). There are a few Mesos tickets to follow if you're interested in keeping up to date, including MESOS-155 for preemption, and MESOS-1474 for inverse offers.

**Colocating Batch and Services**

Running batch and services in a shared Mesos cluster will be key to driving up utilization even further as js84 points out. Check out Project Myriad, an effort to colocate Mesos and YARN workloads in the same cluster. At this time I'm not aware of any large deployments running both batch and services, but it's certainly the direction the community is moving in as it becomes easier for multiple frameworks to run in a shared cluster.

Comment: Thanks Dave for your thorough answer!

Answer (score 4):

At least one additional use case comes to mind: Development SDK for developing distributed applications. If you have a look at [Mesos Frameworks](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/mesos-frameworks/) you will find a number of frameworks which have been developed on top of Mesos. Also interesting [Apple's Siri framework powering Siri](https://mesosphere.com/blog/2015/04/23/apple-details-j-a-r-v-i-s-the-mesos-framework-that-runs-siri/).

Regarding your 1): One additional angle you should keep in mind here is scaling your applications in the same cluster. I.e. at peak load of your website, shift resources easily towards the webservers while scaling down the Hadoop analytical processing.